# Rename Windows Domain User

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, accounts

Any suggestions on renaming a user's domain account? I need to rename the account and make sure their profile folder reflects the change.

Comment: Have you actually tried?  Right click on the user in ADUC and look at the context menu. :/  Oh right, and then rename the profile path.  You can do that part without right-clicking.

Answer (score 7):

Change the name and then change the profile path attribute to match. What's the problem?

Comment: OP may be expecting the file system directory to update as well? Tough to guess based on the question's lack of detail.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties section of the AD account. Change whatever you need to change in the general and account tab. Make sure to update the profile path (if required) and the home folder redirection (if required). If the home folder is redirected, and you update this, you will need to copy the data from the old folder to the new folder or you'll get a phone call in about an hour when they find their 'My Documents' is empty.